# What should be used in "Redirect Urls" when setting up the Javascript web application for Onedrive picker API?

Tags: javascript, picker, onedrive

I am confused in setting up Onedrive file picker App for my website.
This is the error in the popup windows:

error=invalid_request&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+'redirect_uri'+is+not+valid.+The+expected+value+is+'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf'+or+a+URL+which+matches+the+redirect+URI+registered+for+this+client+application.&state=redirect_type%3dauth%26display%3dpage%26request_ts%3d1439903732696%26response_method%3durl%26secure_cookie%3dfalse

I setup everything as described in this website "https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/javascript-picker-saver.htm" but does not work and gives the above error in the url.

Answer (score 1):

The URL for the page hosting the JavaScript picker should be entered as the redirect URL. The JavaScript SDK will automatically use the URL for the page it's loaded on as the redirect URL when authenticating.